# asp.net, enable/disable tabpanel

Tags: asp.net, tabpanel

Why isn't this working?

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel Enabled='<%# User.IsInRole("admin") %>'...
```

While this works:

```
<asp:TextBox Enabled='<%# User.IsInRole("admin") %>'...
```

Comment: Nothing happens, the TabPanel remains enabled no matter what...
Only when typed Enabled="false", it grays out.

The TextBox works as expected and enabled/disables depending on users role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the first example within a binding context (bound control)?  Perhaps you want to use the output directive instead of the binding directive?

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel Enabled='<%= User.IsInRole("admin") %>'
```

**EDIT**: My bad.  `<%= %>` translates into Response.Write, which is not what you want -- too used to ASP.NET MVC, I guess.  The best thing is to make it `runat="server"`, give it an ID and set the value in your code-behind.

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="myTabs" ... />


protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    myTabs.Enabled = User.IsInRole("admin");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm...
That seems correct, missed that. However, now it raises the following,

Parser Error Message: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation '<%= User.IsInRole("admin") %>' for the 'Enabled' property.

Comment: Yeah, <%= %> only works on client-side code.  MS assumes that if you are using a server-side control you will be data binding or setting properties in code-behind.